# Tikz node not displayed in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, nodes

I'm having a problem with tikz game trees on beamer.
The root node should be solid, but doesn't appear at all..
This code works in my paper but not on the slides I'm preparing with Beamer.
Follows code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=20mm,sibling distance=50mm]
\node(0)[solid]{}
child{node{}
    edge from parent node[left]{\textit{No transfer}}
}
child{node{}
    edge from parent node[right]{\textit{Transfer}}
};
\node[above,yshift=4]at(0){Player A};
\node[below]at(0-1){
    Some stuff
};
\node[below]at(0-2){
    More stuff
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Instead of `solid`, write `draw`. Is that what you wanted to see?

Comment: Ok great! Thanks Alenanno, by replacing solid with draw now the node is displayed.. How do I make it round and solid black?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`solid` is a path command, opposed to `dashed`, so if you draw a dashed line and then you place a node on the path that you do not want to appear dashed, you can use solid. It doesn't work to simply `draw` the node, nor it fills it. There are other commands for that. So in your case, use `draw` to show the node's border.

In order to make it round add `circle`, and if you want to fill it, then add `fill=black`.

Comment: Wonderful! can I also change the size?

Comment: Adding "inner sep=0pt, minimum size=0.15cm" did the trick..

Comment: @Andy Oh man sorry! I usually reply very fast, but I've been a bit busy. For smaller sizes you can also just say `inner sep=.15cm`, but it depends on the node and if it has contents.

Comment: no worries! thanks just the same.. it only took some extra searching on S.Ex. :)